# Как параллельно выполнять задания на Java/Kotlin в порядке очереди?

Tags: java, kotlin

Суть такая. Есть задача `scheduleAtFixedRate` который получает некий список файлов, необходимых для загрузки, помещаются они в список `ArrayList<countersFeedsItems>`

```
private void startDemons(){
    Timer timer = new Timer(true);
    System.out.println("TimerTask начал выполнение");
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyTimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            countersFeedsItems = new ViewModel().getCountersFeed();
            System.out.println("запрошен список getCountersFeed()");
                          //дальнейшая необходимая реализация
        }
    }, 10 * 1000, 360*10 * 1000); //10 секунд (10 * 1000 миллисекунд)
    //задание task планируется к выполнению через период в миллисекундах, переданный в параметре delay.
    //Затем задание повторяется повторно периодически - каждые period миллисекунд
}
```

В списке может быть, к примеру 70 значений-ссылок на файлы.
На ум приходит только `Queue`? Но из этого списка обрабатывать нужно пачками, не более 10 штук (одновременно).

И далее, тоже проблема. Скорее всего, Очередь нужно положить в некий цикл(?), который будет "ждать" момента, когда в очередь будет < 10.
При этом, все 10 заданий обрабатываются **параллельно** (у меня через Kotlin-корутины).
 Соответственно, для начала как-то пометить задачу, что она находится в процессе (чтобы не начать ее повторное выполнение). Если задача завершилась с ошибкой (файл не скачался/недоступен), то вернуть эту задачу опять в очередь. 
Если файл скачался, удалить его из очереди. В тот момент, когда задача из очереди удалена, в очередь добавляется новая ссылка на файл.
Кто-нибудь может помочь, как сделать тот самый некий "цикл" который будет следить за количеством и "ожиданием"? Хотя бы какие методы для этого возможны?

Answer (score 1):

Для решения вашей задачи идеально подходит интерфейс [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).
Экземпляр этого интерфейса занимается тем, что параллельно выполняет данные ему (*Runnable*) задания.

Создать экземпляр *ExecutorService* выполняющий не более чем 10 задач одновременно можно вызвав `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10)`.

Для добавления задания у *ExecutorService* есть метод [submit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit(java.lang.Runnable)).

*ExecutorService* не завершает работу сам, так как даже после того как все задания будут выполнены, он останется в ожидании новых. А чтобы все-таки завершить его работу, можно поступить следующим образом. Сначала вызвать метод [shutdown](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown()), чтобы показать что новые задания больше не будут поступать, а затем вызвать метод [awaitTermination](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) с нужным временем ожидания, который (если успеет) завершит работу *ExecutorService* после выполнения всех оставшихся задач.

Comment: И очень советую создавать Runnable через лямбды:
() -> { ваш код; }

Comment: Согласен, хоть и во времена корутин решение выглядит немного олдскульно :), но отлично подходит для такого типа задач.